# URLLoader ain't loading any XML File

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to parse an XML file with URLLoader, i already followed 2 or 3 tutorials and none of them actually work. Here is the code:

```
var myXML:XML = new XML(); 

var XML_URL:String = "http://www.example.com/Sample3.xml"; 

var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL); 

MonsterDebugger.trace(myLoader.bytesLoaded,"bl");

myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded); 

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    MonsterDebugger.trace("Data loaded.","test 10"); 
}
```

The Loader doesn't load anything, the "bytesLoaded" are always 0.

I'm probably doing something stupid, any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: you try loading some real XML file or this one from `example.com`? may be it is who actually makes the problem?

Comment: I've tried a different link such as http://www.kirupa.com/net/files/sampleXML.xml and it doesn't work too :/

Comment: so download it to the folder where your `swf` file placed. and then change this line : `var XML_URL:String = "http://www.example.com/Sample3.xml"; ` like this : `var XML_URL:String = "Sample3.xml"; `

Answer (score 0):

try it with:

```
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
myLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, xmlProgress);
myLoader.load(myXMLURL);


function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    myXML = XML(myLoader.data); 
    MonsterDebugger.trace("Data loaded.","test 10"); 
}

function xmlProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    MonsterDebugger.trace(myLoader.bytesLoaded,"bl"); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried that but the program doesn't even enter the "xmlProgress" function. So he doesn't print anything inside that.